# Creating an image gallery using html image tag in a php for loop

Tags: php, html, image

I want to create an online image gallery. I have a folder containing n number of thumbnails and they are name as `tn_1.jpg, tn_2.jpg and so on`.This is the code i am planning to implement.

```
<?php

for ($i=1;$i<=n;$i++)
{
echo '<img src="images/tn_'.$i.'.jpg"/><br>';
}
?>
```

Do you think this is a good way of creating an online gallery or should i follow another method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are running a framework on top of your vanilla PHP (either PHP or JavaScript), this would be your only way to display the images in a folder on your web page.

You just need to add logic to get the names of all the files within that directory and then run the loop.

```
$files = scandir('/path/to/image/directory');
foreach($files as $file){
    echo '<img src="/path/to/image/directory/' . $file . '"/><br>';
}
```